# Error joining DC as a child to Forest DC | The specified argument 'ChildName' was not recognized

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I have the following scripts running. (**This question was posted on Superuser and I have been asked to put it here**).

Basically both scripts create files at runtime, and then the server restarts and run the newly created files, however there is error when the child DC joins the forest, even though it joins successfully.

**Forest DC**

```
$path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\AddForest.ps1"
New-Item $path -ItemType File
Set-Content -Path $path -Value @'
Install-WindowsFeature -name AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools

Install-ADDSForest `
-CreateDnsDelegation:$false `
-DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-DomainMode "WinThreshold" `
-DomainName "electric-petrol.ie" `
-DomainNetbiosName "ELECTRIC-PETROL" `
-ForestMode "WinThreshold" `
-InstallDns:$true `
-LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-NoRebootOnCompletion:$false `
-SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" `
-Force:$true `
-SafeModeAdministratorPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Passw0rd' -Force -AsPlainText)

$pathb = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\RestartNetworkServices.ps1"
Remove-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "AddForest"
Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "RestartNetworkServices" -Value "powershell.exe $pathb"

write-host "deleting used files.."
$path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\AddForest.ps1"
Remove-Item -Path $path -Force

restart-computer
'@

$pathb = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\RestartNetworkServices.ps1"
New-Item $pathb -ItemType File
Set-Content -Path $pathb -Value @'
Restart-Service -Name NlaSvc -force

$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Remove-ItemProperty $RegPath -Name "AutoAdminLogon"
Remove-ItemProperty $RegPath -Name "DefaultUsername"
Remove-ItemProperty $RegPath -Name "DefaultPassword"

Remove-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "RestartNetworkServices"

write-host "deleting used files.."
$pathb = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\RestartNetworkServices.ps1"
Remove-Item -Path $pathb -Force
'@
$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUsername" -Value "Administrator" -type String  
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value "Passw0rd" -type String

Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "AddForest" -Value "powershell.exe $path"

write-host "deleting used files.."
$pathd = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\Abbeydorney_DC1.ps1"
Remove-Item -Path $pathd -Force

restart-computer
```

**Child DC**

```
$patha = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\JoinDomain.ps1"
New-Item $patha -ItemType File
Set-Content -Path $patha  -Value @'
$srvr = "AbbeydorneyDC2"
$domname = "electric-petrol.ie"
$dom = ($domname).Remove(15,3)
$pass = convertto-securestring -string "Passw0rd" -asplaintext -force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ("$dom\Administrator", $pass)
add-computer -domainname $domname -Credential $cred

Remove-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "JoinDomain"

$pathb = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\JoinForest.ps1"
Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "JoinForest" -Value "powershell.exe $pathb"

write-host "deleting used files.."
$pathc = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\JoinDomain.ps1"
Remove-Item -Path $pathc -Force

restart-computer
'@

$pathc = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\JoinForest.ps1"
New-Item $pathc -ItemType File
Set-Content -Path $pathc -Value @'
$srvr = "AbbeydorneyDC2"
$domname = "electric-petrol.ie"
$dom = ($domname).Remove(15,3)
$pass = convertto-securestring -string "Passw0rd" -asplaintext -force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ("$dom\Administrator", $pass)

Install-WindowsFeature -name AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools

Install-ADDSDomain `
-credential $cred `
-CreateDnsDelegation:$true `
-DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-DomainMode "WinThreshold" `
-NewDomainName "Abbeydorney" `
-DomainType ChildDomain `
-ParentDomainName $domname `
-InstallDns:$true `
-LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-NoRebootOnCompletion:$false `
-SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" `
-safemodeadministratorpassword $pass `
-Force:$true

Install-WindowsFeature -Name 'DHCP' –IncludeManagementTools

Remove-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "JoinForest"

$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Remove-ItemProperty $RegPath -Name "AutoAdminLogon"
Remove-ItemProperty $RegPath -Name "DefaultUsername"
Remove-ItemProperty $RegPath -Name "DefaultPassword"

write-host "deleting used files.."
$pathc = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\JoinForest.ps1"
Remove-Item -Path $pathc -Force

restart-computer
'@

$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1"
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUsername" -Value "Administrator" -type String  
Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value "Passw0rd" -type String

Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" -Name "JoinDomain" -Value "powershell.exe $patha"

write-host "deleting used files.."
$pathd = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\Abbeydorney_DC2.ps1"
Remove-Item -Path $pathd -Force

restart-computer
```

**Error (Even though the child DC joins Forest successfully)**

```
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\JoinForest.ps1:9 char:1
+ Install-ADDSDomain -credential $cred -CreateDnsDelegation:$true -Data ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-ADDSDomain], TestFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Test.VerifyDcPromoCore.DCPromo.General.77,Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Deployment.PowerShell.Commands.InstallADDSDomainCommand

Message        : Verification of prerequisites for Domain Controller promotion failed. The specified argument 'ChildName' was not recognized.

Context        : Test.VerifyDcPromoCore.DCPromo.General.77
RebootRequired : False
Status         : Error
```

Any thoughts as to what causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is normal as found out via technet forums.